# Addition of two algebraic integer numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is the addition of two algebraic integer numbers also algebraic?

I, guess it is, but i can't prove it.
I wonder if multiplication of them is also algebraic.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh, that question is not about algebraic *integers*.

Comment: Yep, that answers.  Dang I was putting my thoughts into words for this.

Comment: Hmm, I think it be straightforward (famous last words) that if the leading coefficient of P and Q are one the resultant polynomial will have coefficient 1... I hope.

Comment: This question is most likely a duplicate but I couldn't find one with an actual answer.

Comment: Note that [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217551/348926) contains a proof of this fact, although the question is a bit different.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos But it openly states that the aim is to prove the set of algebraic integers is a ring.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

- $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer iff $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-module.
- If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are an algebraic integers, then $\mathbf Z[\alpha,\beta]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-module.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Number_theory and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer#Facts for a different take.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, there's a Field of algebraic numbers, so yes.

quick look here should provide you with an insight https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number#The_field_of_algebraic_numbers

Comment: The question is about algebraic *integers* and whether they form a ring.

Comment: oh wow, absolutely mis-read the question. I'm so sorry. A quick search should give Helia.alipanah a pretty good insight anyway.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer